# ErrorDocument 404 with server host variable?

Tags: php, configuration, http-status-code-404, apache

I've got a site with a sub-domain.
There are two different sites, one is accessible at domain.ph or www.domain.ph,
another with a sub-domain, suppose its health.domain.ph

So, both are on the same apache server, but for each domain 404 errors should be handled differently... if we wrong at the main domain it should send us domain.ph/404.php, but if we try to open non-existing page on health.domain.ph it should send us to health.domain.ph/404.php

I wanted  to add a server variable to ErrorDocument 404  %???% /404.php to httpd.conf, but I couldn't find anything... is there any variables I can use in the config file?

Comment: What's happening at the moment? By default the use of ErrorDocument 404 /404.php should be relative to the domain that your on.

Comment: Oh, cool if this is so. Testing at the localhost at the moment, playing with folders... Thanks then, it will save me time!